# Hacer una consulta SQL que varia sobre una tabla en Python

Tags: sql, postgresql, python-2.7

Quiero escribir el resultado de varias consultas SQL que estan dependen de una tabla `res[ids]`.

```
        for i, ids in enumerate(self.res['ids']):
            print ids
            cur.execute("""--- hashtag describiendo los grupos de subscriber_id 
            SELECT COUNT(swipe.eclipse_id), 
            subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
            FROM subscriber_hashtag
            INNER JOIN eclipse_hashtag ON eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id = subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN swipe ON subscriber_hashtag.subscriber_id = swipe.subscriber_id
            WHERE swipe.subscriber_id in %s 
            GROUP BY subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
                ORDER BY COUNT(swipe.eclipse_id) DESC;""",
            (tuple(self.res.iloc[i]['ids']),))
        n = cur.fetchall()
        print "n : "
        print n
        listado_description = [{"count": elem[0], "hashtag_id": elem[1],"eclipse_id": elem[2]} for elem in n]
        f= open("listado_description.js","w+")
        for item in listado_description:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)
        f.closed
```

Por lo momento parace que solo la ultima consulata esta guardado en `listado_description` porque no hay ninguno cosa en el pero cuando intento hacerlo con cosas de `res[ids]` obteno un resultado.

Comment: Solo estás obteniendo la última consulta ya que tu `cur.fetchall()` está fuera del bucle, solo estás extrayendo la última consulta que se ejecuta en el `for`. Tendrías que hacerlo todo dentro del bucle, es decir, ejecutar un `cur.fetchall()` por cada `cur.execute()` que hagas.

Comment: Además hacer un ciclo para disparar la misma consulta es poco óptimo, yo vería de resolver todo en una sola sentencia SQL, no veo que sea demasiado compleja para no hacerlo. Podrías armar un string como `ids = ",".join(self.res['ids'])` y hacer una sola consulta usando `WHERE swipe.subscriber_id in ( ' + ids + ')`